# Find angle from 3x3 matrix components

Tags: matrix

I have a 3x3 rotation matrix:

```
[  cos( angle ) sin( angle ) 0 ]
[ -sin( angle ) cos( angle ) 0 ]
[  0            0            1 ]
```

How do I work out `angle`?

The methods I'm using now to do this is:

```
void Mat3::SetAngle( const float angle ) {
    m[ 0 + 0 * 3 ] = cos( angle );
    m[ 1 + 0 * 3 ] = sin( angle );
    m[ 0 + 1 * 3 ] = -sin( angle );
    m[ 1 + 1 * 3 ] = cos( angle );
}
```

And to retreive it I'm using:

```
float Mat3::GetAngle( void ) {
    return atan2( m[ 1 + 0 * 3], m[ 0 + 0 * 3] );
}
```

I'm testing it like this:

```
Mat3 m;
m.SetAngle( 179.0f );
float a = m.GetAngle();
```

And a ends up being 3.0708115 which is not correct.

Comment: which programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm using C++ language.

Comment: looks like a rotation around the z axis... also the sines' signs :) seem interchanged.  Make sure it's radians.

Comment: I think, you need convert your angle to radians before using it in SetAngle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sin and cos take arguments in radians, while atan2 returns an angle in radians.

```
179 rad = 3.070811 + 14 * 2 * pi rad
```

which is the same angle as 3.070811 rad.

You could either pass in the required angle as radians and convert the GetAngle result

```
m.SetAngle( 179.0f * M_PI / 180.0f );
float a = m.GetAngle() * 180.0f / M_PI;
```

or modify the class to take degrees

```
void Mat3::SetAngle( const float angleDeg ) {
    angleRad = angleDeg / 180.0f * M_PI;
    m[ 0 + 0 * 3 ] = cos( angleRad );
    // etc
}

float Mat3::GetAngle( void ) {
    return atan2( m[ 1 + 0 * 3], m[ 0 + 0 * 3] ) * 180.0f / M_PI;
}
```

Either way I'd suggest documenting which unit your class expects.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `atan( sin/ cos)` function, or `atan2( sin, cos)` if it's available.

The simple single-argument `atan( s/c)` is the basic method. That answers angles from nearly -PI to +PI (approaching -90 degrees to approaching +90 degrees), but you will need to special-case a divide-by-0 at +/- 90 degrees exactly.

You also need to modify the result angle for "cosine(X) < 0", that is for the other 180 degrees of the circle.

See:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2(double,%20double)